# Refresh a div after a record had been added

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've posted the same question before, but I didn't get any feedback!However, I still can't solve this problem.
So I have an index.php which displays users in my database. I'm using a jquery UI dialog form to add new user.The problem is that I want to display a message when a new user is added and show it in the table that displays the user. I succeeded to add records to the database, but I have to refresh the entire page to make the new items added visible in the table. Here is my table :

```
<div id="users">
    <tr>
        <td>//users's informations</td>
    </tr>
</div>
```

the jquery code that adds the users :

```
//some vars
dataString = //dataString
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "create.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function () {
        $(#users).load("index.php", function () {
            display_message("user added");)
        };
    }
});
$(this).dialog("close");
return false;
```

So when I click to create a new user ;it just shows me a blank page of index.php loading. Please help, thank you.

Comment: what's in your display_message function?

Answer (score 1):

you have forgotten to place `"` around the selector

```
 success: function() {
                 $("#users").load("index.php", function() {
-------------------^
                      display_message("user added");
                      )};
               }
```

EDIT:

> but I have to refresh the entire page to make the new items added visible in the table.

if you want to refresh the whole page either in the success callback or after the dialog close put this line

```
location.reload(true);
```

Comment: Yes I did it before but I won't be able to display the message.Only if there is a way to call it after the page had been refreshed, which i don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are retreiving user's info from your ajax's request:

```
success: function(userinfos) {
                 $("#users").append($('<tr><td>'+userinfos+'</td></tr>'))
                 display_message("user added");
               }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your create.php, format the div with html. Make sure this html is printed in the page and not stored in a variable.

This is the format which you want to show in index.php. Then on your success function write it in the below way.

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "create.php",
data: dataString,
success: function (data) {
        $("#users tr td").html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this too, but I'll will have problem showing the pagination if I exceed the number of users allowed in one page.Almost all the code is in php, this is why I just want to refresh the part that displays the users.Because it will be added automatically after refreshing it.

Comment: You wont have. You just have to be careful when you format your data. In pagination if each page has 10 records, make sure that you format your html data only for 10 users.

Comment: Sure. Let me know if you get stuck.

Comment: jut a question, I'm just new in jquery! when using the html or append function.Can i do things like: append($(<tr><td><?php $user-> firstname ?> </td></tr>) ?

Comment: ALright. Good question. The basic difference between .html() and append() is that, when you use .html(), it will delete the contents of the div and get new data into it. But when you use append(), it wont delete/overwrite any data, it will just add the data into it.

Comment: Yes you can. But you have few errors in your code. Format it this way.

append("<tr><td><?php echo $user->firstname; ?></td></tr>");

Comment: and can I do the same thing with html ? I mean html("<tr><td><?php echo $user->firstname; ?></td></tr>"); ? sorry if I ask too much.

Comment: Yes, ofcourse you can. But when you use .html over a div, it will replace the contents of that div. eg. <div id="test">hello</div>. now when you write $("#test").html("<tr>some text</tr>"), your div will become <div id="text">some text</div>

Comment: We are here to help you and we really dont get bugged with questions. We appreciate your questions if they are logical.

Comment: I did what you said, and I succeeded to add a row to the table, However there is no data in it! I can't figure out how to retrieve data from the last record added ,any ideas?

Comment: Its difficult to write the code here. But i can tell you the logic. Basically when you are adding the data in the database, you already have the data handy with you. Store this data into a variable and echo it. Receive this data through ajax and use .append() or .html() to display it.